# Cycle in Directed graph Can't understand why it does not work

Tags: c++, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

Here is my code:- I use a map to keep track of nodes visited in current call to explore function. If some node is already visited and present in map, then i return a cycle. Also to every new call to explore from dfs function i clear map as well. It seems my code classifies come acyclic graphs as cyclic. But those inputs are huge (1000 nodes and 1000 edges) so can't debug it.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void explore(vector< vector<int> > &adj, vector<bool> &visited, int start, int &flag, map<int, bool> &occured)
{
   visited[start] = true;
   occured[start] = true;
   for(int i = 0; i < adj[start].size(); i++)
   {
       if(!visited[adj[start][i]])
       {
           explore(adj, visited, adj[start][i], flag, occured);
       }
       else if(occured[adj[start][i]])
       {
           flag = 1;
       }
   }
}

int dfs(vector< vector<int> > &adj, vector<bool> &visited)
{
    int flag = 0;
    map<int, bool> occured;
    for(int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
    {    
        if(!visited[i])
        {
            occured.clear();
            explore(adj, visited, i, flag, occured);
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            return flag;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int acyclic(vector<vector<int> > &adj) 
{
    vector<bool> visited(adj.size(), false);
    return dfs(adj, visited);
}

int main() 
{
    size_t n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<int> > adj(n, vector<int>());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) 
    {
        int x, y;
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        adj[x - 1].push_back(y - 1);
    }
    std::cout << acyclic(adj);
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I know it includes lots of constants and other things but here i m not concerned with it

Comment: That was not an answer, it was just a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this graph

```
              1
           /   |
         /     |
        v     |
       2      | 
         \     |
          V  V
             3
```

It's an acyclic graph, but your implementation will classify it as cyclic. The reason is that when you start traversing, let's say from node 1, the `visited` and `occurred` data structure are in the following state,

1. ```
     1 ----> 2

    visited: [true, true, false]
    occurred: [{1: true}, {2: true}]
   ```
2. ```
    1 ----> 2 --->3

   visited: [true, true, true]
   occurred: [{1: true}, {2: true}]
   ```
3. ```
    1 ----> 3

   visited: [true, true, true]
   occurred: [{1: true}, {2: true}, {3: true}]
   ```

In the backtracking step (3.) the node 3 is already marked as visited and sets the flag. To fix this you need to reset the occurred state of a node after you've visited all the nodes in that path.

```
void explore(vector< vector<int> > &adj, vector<bool> &visited, int start, int &flag, map<int, bool> &occured)
{
   visited[start] = true;
   occured[start] = true;
   for(int i = 0; i < adj[start].size(); i++)
   {
       if(!visited[adj[start][i]])
       {
           explore(adj, visited, adj[start][i], flag, occured);
       }
       else if(occured[adj[start][i]])
       {
           flag = 1;
       }
   }
   occured[start] = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanku very much for investing your time in this. I understood